# How can I control when the component's createContent function is fired?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have an app which needs to check if the user has multiple accounts when it is first loaded. Most of them don't, so they should be taken straight into the main app view.
If they do have multiple accounts, they should be taken to a screen which allows them to select with which account they want to continue. The users with only one account should never see this selection page.

I have an OData call which returns the result of a backend check to see if the user has multiple accounts.

How can I dynamically set the rootView property of the component's metadata so it acts according to the behaviour defined above?

My research suggests if the `rootView` property is not set in the component metadata, the root view must be defined in the createContent() method.

My problem seems to stem around the asynchronous call to the OData, with createContent() executing before the OData result functions have set the variable to decide which view to see.

**EDIT: I've changed the title to better reflect the likely cause of my problem. How can I keep the asynchronous calls but prevent createContent() from eventing before those calls are completed? Adding in something like the EventBus still doesn't work as it seems the application won't wait for it, and I just get an error about not being able to find the view.**

My code below:

Declaration at the top of the file. By default view is the App since most users don't have multiple accounts. The multiple accounts is a rarer exception.

```
var sRootView = "view.App"; //default value of root view  
sap.ui.core.UIComponent.extend("MY_APP.Component", {
```

Component.js

```
init: function(){
...

this.oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("/odatasvc");
that = this;
var aBatch = [];
aBatch.push(this.oModel.createBatchOperation("/multiple_account_check", "GET"));

makeCall = function(){
  var oDef = $.Deferred();
  utils.oDataCalls.read(that.oModel, aBatch, oDef);
  return oDef.promise();
};

var promise = makeCall();
var aResults = [];

promise.done(function(data) {
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    aResults.push(data);
  }
  that.checkAccounts(aResults[0]);
});
```

The createContent function.

```
createContent : function(){ 
    var oView = sap.ui.view({ 
      id : "meViewId",
      viewName : sRootView,
      type : "XML" });
    return oView;
  },
```

The function to check OData result for multiple accounts.

```
  checkAccounts : function(aResults){
    if(aResults.length == 1){ //one account
      that.oRouter.navTo("home");
    }
    else if(aResults.length > 1){ //multiple accounts
      sRootView = "view.multipleAccountsView"; //changed value used in createContent    
      that.oRouter.navTo("multipleAccounts");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Would anyone be able to tell me where the createContent function is called from? I want to try controlling when that function calls createContent.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to make the OData call synchronously by passing *async* as *false* to ODataModel method [read](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html#read). E.g:

```
oModel.read{"path", {async: false}};
```

If you implement this inside *utils.oDataCalls.read*, it might also require reworking the promise in that function.

Comment: I've tried this but the problem seems to lie with the createContent function still firing before the app can set the var for which view it should point to. In any case, the OData services I'm working with are somewhat slow so I don't want to provide bad UX by making them synchronous. Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: How about if you just return a view with a loader from createContent and then navigate to the appropriate view once the OData call is ready?

Other option would be to make the OData call before creating your Component and then pass the length as init parameter to the Component.

I'm not sure whether you can defer the call to createContent. But if you do find a way, please, inform how.

Comment: Where would I place this OData call before the Component? My component is the starting point of the app, and I don't think putting OData calls in the index.html is good practise. As for the createContent issue, I'm trying to look up where it's actually being called from but having no luck trying to override these functions.

Comment: I would say index.html but I agree that it's probably not the best way.

It seems that createContent is called on UIComponent.init. So you could try replacing that and only call prototype's init after the OData call has been made. E.g.:

`code
yourComp.Component.prototype.init = function(){
        odatacall();
 sap.ui.core.UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this);
`

Though this might introduce some side effects.

Comment: Didn't get the formatting to work, but call `code sap.ui.core.UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this);` after the odatacall is ready.